# Django paginator returning same data on seperate pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

**Problem**:
I am developing an application in django that uses paginator for the list page of a model, it is set to display 25 instances of the model per page, when i view the first page everything works fine but when i move to the second page it shows some values from the first again. i have checked the database and there is no data duplication either.

**Cause/attempted solutions**:
while not 100% i believe the problem originates from the order_by in the queryset but even after changing and removing the problem persists

**Details**:
snips of list for the first and second page

First: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pi6F.jpg 
Second: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4jn8.jpg (note CO01, 4 and 5 appear again)

Views.py:

```
def view_jobs(request):
    query_results = Job.objects.select_related('contract').order_by('-active', '-order_date')

    paginate = Paginator(query_results, 25)
    page_no = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginate.get_page(page_no)

    context = {"query_results": page_obj}

    return render(request, 'view_jobs.html', context)
```

view_jobs.html:

```
<table id="PageTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">
            <h6>Number</h6>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for item in query_results %}
        <td>
          <small>{{ item|filter_prep:"order" }}</small>
          {% if item.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ item.help_text }}</small>
          {% endif %}
          {% for error in item.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if query_results.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ query_results.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ query_results.number }} of {{ query_results.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if query_results.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ query_results.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ query_results.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

feel free to ask for any extra details.

Comment: Does any data insert to your DB in this duration?

Comment: none, it is just a query to display the models from the DB, i have just checked with PGadmin and there is no data duplication either